# Cracking sound on headphones

Tags: sound, audio

There is a cracking sound when I play music via headphones on my laptop. The built in speakers play back just fine. Also cracking noise when recording audio via Loom. What's going on?
I think this started after I paired the laptop with a bluetooth speaker.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you enter the following in the terminal:

```
pulseaudio -k 
# or
killall pulseaudio
```

Comment: Nothing happened after entering either of those commands